# get a template resource - full yaml script code of helm (K8S)

Tags: templates, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

For helm command: `helm create <chart name>` there are several different templates, that are auto-generated.

i.e Deployment.yaml is a template of kind: Deployment.

When I run the command: `kubectl api-resources`, I found that there are many template resources.

I need to auto generate a resource (or get it from a hub template), i.e of kind: Pod, which is in the list of `kubectl api-resources` command.

How can I get that predefined template, such ad Pod template easily (the full yaml script for the template).

Thanks.

Comment: To extend the answer below, you can use [`kubectl create`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#create) for some main resources to get the structure in `yaml` - like `kubectl create job test --image=image --dry-run=client -o yaml` or `kubectl run test --image=image --dry-run=client -o yaml` for pod.

Comment: It is good for "Job", but i didn't figure out how creating the template for "Pod".  kubectl create job test --image=k8s.io/api/core/v1 --dry-run=client -o yaml 

The above create a job. How can I create a Pod template?

Comment: Just pay attention to the second option in my previous comment :) where it's "kubectl run"

Comment: The first is kind of template for job, and the second for pod, but if I want any one of the list that api-resources provides?

Comment: Check the link I shared under 'kubectl create'. There are only certain resource types which can be created this way. For everything else you can try to find ready helm templates with 'helm search hub pod -o yaml' and follow the links. Unfortunately that's the furthest you can do, at least by what I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm create` outputs a fairly fixed structure.  There is not an arbitrary resource generator, but rather a "usually works" template for a typical single-Deployment application.  (See [`pkg/chartutil/create.go`](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/chartutil/create.go) in the Helm source.)

If you want to add new templates, you need to use a text editor to create a new template file in the chart's `templates` directory.  I'd recommend following the pattern in the existing templates for objects' `metadata:`, and maybe even starting by copying the existing generated `deployment.yaml`.  Looking in the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/) and especially the [API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/) can help you find the fields for objects that are part of the standard Kubernetes system.

You usually do not want to create a bare Pod, but instead a Deployment or occasionally a StatefulSet.  If you need to add a second Deployment to your application, copy the existing generated `deployment.yaml` file and edit the fields as needed.

Comment: That what I don't want to do.
I just thought there is a site like dock hub, that have the whole template, or I can just reveal the template by a simple command.

helm create doesn't help much. I know that, but it has some minimal templates that it creates. There are lot of templates. To write them "by hands" it little massy, and I need to use not just one or two predefined template.

Is there any better technique to create template (of any kind)?

Comment: with your advise and also @moonkotte advise - I just create a command like: kubectl create job test --image=k8s.io/api/core/v1 --dry-run=client -o yaml (while the image is in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/), but the kind is "Job", when I need the kind to be "Pod"